# Explode/Decompose Polyline Network with MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, line, explode

I have a network of polylines which possibly include multi polylines as well. I wish to decompose these polylines into their fundemental line segments so I can produce the following table:

```
Link_ID | BegNodX | BegNodeY | EndNodeX | EndNodeY | Distance
--------------------------------------------------------------
0001    | 554612  |  456375  | 557864   |  455487  |  0.348
0002    | 554632  |  456355  | 557841   |  456522  |  3.454
....
```

I've noticed there is a Mapinfo tools such as Polybrk.mbx by Mr. Dressel but this tool only explodes one polyline selection. I need a whole network exploding and I do not wish to do each one manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code:
I'll leave column link_ID and distance to you.

```
include "mapbasic.def"

dim h,i,m,n as integer
dim obj as object

fetch first from input_table
while not eot(input_table)
  obj = input_table.obj
  if objectinfo(obj,obj_info_type)=OBJ_TYPE_PLINE then
    m = objectinfo(obj,OBJ_INFO_NPOLYGONS)
    for h = 1 to m
      n = objectinfo(obj,OBJ_INFO_NPOLYGONS+h)
      for i = 1 to n-1
        print ObjectNodeX(obj,h,i)+"  "+
              ObjectNodeY(obj,h,i)+"  "+
              ObjectNodeX(obj,h,i+1)+"  "+
              ObjectNodeY(obj,h,i+1)
      next
    next
  elseif objectinfo(obj,obj_info_type)=OBJ_TYPE_LINE then
    print ObjectGeography(obj,OBJ_GEO_LINEBEGX)+"  "+
          ObjectGeography(obj,OBJ_GEO_LINEBEGY)+"  "+
          ObjectGeography(obj,OBJ_GEO_LINEENDX)+"  "+
          ObjectGeography(obj,OBJ_GEO_LINEENDY)
  end if
  fetch next from input_table
wend
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks like what I'm after. Do I need to have MapBasic to run this or can I do it from MapInfo (Options> Show MapBasic Window)?

Comment: You have to compile it in MapBasic then run resulting MBX file.

Comment: MapBasic window do not allow loops, conditional branching and a lot more. So yes, you need mapbasic and it isn't ready to run - just a starting point.

Comment: Nice example on how to loop thru nodes in a polyline (or polygon)

Comment: Just as a quick comment, MapBasic is free and in my opinion MapInfo's great and undying strength. To compile and run Uffe's wonderfully elegant script, you will need it.

Personally wouldnt use MapInfo at all if it wasn't for MapBasic.

You can download it from http://www.pbinsight.com.au/support/product-downloads/for/mapbasic

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of MapInfo Professional (from v9.5 I think) you'll find the tool MapCAD.
MapCAD has a number of built-in tools - CAD like tools.

You can find MapCAD in the Tool Manager.

One of these tools is called Split to Lines which does exactly what it claims: It splits polylines into lines

Comment: Great, I believe I have v10.0 so I'll check it out. Thank you!